# Case question regarding some text from Brahms' "Ein deutsches Requiem"

Tags: word-choice, preposition, grammatical-case, dative

I am a choral singer who is slowly trying to learn German.  I have a question about why the dative case is being used in some text from Johannes Brahms' *Ein deutsches Requiem*.

In particular, there is a movement with the following text [1]:

> Siehe, meine Tage sind einer Handbreit vor dir...

This comes from Psalm 39 and the phrase, as I understand it, would be roughly translated as:

> Behold, my days are as a handbreadth before Thee...

I understand that this is a historical work (composed between 1865 and 1868), but I am confused why `eine Handbreit` here is declined in the dative case (at least that's what I assume the `einer` is marking).  I understand that `vor` in this situation takes the dative case, which is why `before Thee` is translated as `vor dir`, but why is `Handbreit` also in dative?  It seems like the nominative case would make more sense here, since we are using `sein` to say `My days are...`

At any rate, I assume I'm missing something, be it how `vor` actually works, or this is some historical artifact.

Vielen Dank!

[1] http://www.classical-music.com/article/brahmss-german-requiem-text (Full text, see movement 3 for the passage in question.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to GermanSE. What a great first question! :)

Comment: Please note that in the original, it's written not `Handbreit` but `Hand breit`, i.e. with a space.

Comment: I would have guessed that this comes from a clumsily translated ablative; but appearently, the original is just _ecce breves posuisti dies meos_ -- "behold, you have made my days short". Strange translation.

Answer (score 3):

The word *handbreit* is composed from two nouns originally: it comes from *die Breite einer Hand* or, with different word order as it was quite usual in that times: *einer Hand Breite*

From there the composit word handbreit evolved.

That explains why in your sentence the article is written in genitive (not dative) clause:

> Siehe, meine Tage sind einer Hand Breit(e) vor dir...

Or (in more modern word order):

> Siehe, meine Tage sind (um) die Breite einer Hand vor dir...

You can read more about this definition in the [dictionary of the Brothers Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Handbreit). There you even find another example from the bible with the same genitive clause emphasis of mine)

> HANDBREITE, f. die breite einer hand: und eine leisten umb her, einer handbreit hoch. 2 Mos. 25, 25; ein rise .. sechs ellen und **einer handbreit hoch**.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you for this explanation!

Comment: *Breit* is probably the adjective, not the noun *Breite*, as indicated by the small *b* in the original.

Comment: Yes, today that is the meaning. But the origin is The noun, thats why genitive... today with an adjective of course it would be nominative and that is exactly the question of the op

Comment: I disagree. I wouldn't focus on *handbreit*, but on *ist einen Meter breit*; *ist die Breite eines Meters* is not really acceptable (and I don't think it ever was).

Comment: I have no idea how this relates to the question or anything... but ok: Then please explain the dative „einer handbreit“ in the question... I‘m really interested now.... probably your answer is simply: he didn‘t know better...

Comment: Aber vielleicht überzeugt Dich ja das [Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&lemma=Handbreit)... aber die haben vermutlich auch keine Ahnung...

Comment: Dort wird *Handbreit* als Zusammenrückung von *Hand* und *breit* erklärt, also ohne Genitiv.

Comment: Das steht: "einer handbreit hoch". Was wäre das für ein Fall, wenn nicht Genitiv? Höchstens noch Dativ.

Comment: Ok, I give up: you are right, and I am not even able to read the texts in the links I post...

Comment: @Nico: thanx for the example. Added it to the answer and this -imho- really improves it

Comment: Daß *handbreit* nicht von *die Breite einer Hand* / *einer Hand Breite* kommt, sieht man, wenn man sich *das Haarbreit* und *den Fußbreit* anschaut. Abgesehen davon ging es nie um *handbreit*, sondern *einer hand breit*.

Answer (score 3):

Luther's translation of Psalm 39 reads:

> Sihe / meine Tage sind *einer hand* **breit** bey dir<sup>[1](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Der+Psalter/Psalm+39#1545_6)</sup>

The adjective *breit* is the [subject complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement) of *ist*, i.e.

> Meine Tage sind **breit**.

In order to specify how broad, the genitive *einer hand* is added to the adjective *breit*. In New High German, such measurements are in the accusative.

> *einen Meter* **lang, breit, hoch**
> *einen Kilometer* **weit**
> *einen Monat* **lang**

In Luther's time, the genitive and the accusative were in competition with each other. Luther also has the accusative.

> Vier ecket sol es sein vnd zwifach / *eine hand* **breit** sol seine lenge sein<sup>[2](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Das+zweite+Buch+Mose+(Exodus)/Exodus+28#1545_16)</sup>

In the end, the accusative won out. See also Paul's *Deutsche Grammatik*, III, § [244](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11022622_00355.html?zoom=1).

Some further examples with a genitive and an adjective from Luther's bible (all  taken from the [DWB](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB)):

> Sollen denn die Weiber jres Leibs frucht essen / die jüngsten Kindlin *einer spannen* **lang**?<sup>[3](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Die+Klaglieder+Jeremi%C3%A4/Klagelieder+2#1545_20)</sup>
>
> Ein Fenster soltu dran machen oben an / *einer ellen* **gros**.<sup>[4](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Das+erste+Buch+Mose+(Genesis)/Genesis+6#1545_16)</sup>
>
> Vnd gab jm kein Erbteil drinnen /auch nicht *eines fusses* **breit**<sup>[5](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Neue+Testament/Die+Apostelgeschichte/Apostelgeschichte+7#1545_5)</sup>
>
> Vnd es giengen Leisten herumb / hinein werds gebogen / *einer Quehrhand* **hoch**<sup>[6](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Luther,+Martin/Luther-Bibel+1545/Das+Alte+Testament/Der+Prophet+Hesekiel/Ezechiel+40#1545_43)</sup>

Comment: "In Luther's time, the genitive and the accusative were in competition with each other." Any sources?

Comment: This is fascinating; thank you!