# Why is the size written in accusative?

Tags: grammatical-case, accusative

In the following sentence

> Es ist nur einen Zentimeter groß.

why is it written with Accusative and not Nominative?

Answer (score 21):

This so-called **accusative of measure** (*Akkusativ des Maßes*) stands with certain adjectives such as *groß, breit, hoch, weit, schwer*. Some examples:

1. Sie dachte *einen Augenblick lang* nach.
2. *Einen Tag später* hatte man das Problem gelöst.
3. Ihr Ziel lag nur *einen Steinwurf entfernt*.

Adjectives can also stand with a dative, genitive or a prepositional phrase:

4. Ihre Ehe schien *dem Ende nah*.
5. Er ist ein *seiner Sache sicherer* Jurist.
6. Alle waren *neugierig auf das Ergebnis*.

The adjective forms a unit with the dependent phrase that can appear in first position (2.) and prenominally (5.).

See also [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/65913/35111), [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/56420/35111), [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/67612/35111).

Comment: _"Einen Tag später hatte man das Problem gelöst."_ is a wrong example, because time specification in German always goes with Akkusativ independent of the prepositions (does it not?).

Comment: This answer makes it look as if the adverbial accusative stood only with certain adjectives. It can also stand with verbs or, rarely, with nouns.

Comment: @gented I assume you're thinking of things like *er spazierte den ganzen Tag*, where *den ganzen Tag* specifies a duration. *Später* plus accusative is quite different: 1. it specifies a point in time; 2. the case is governed by the adjective (i.e. adjective and accusative form a unit, other adjectives demand other cases); 3. the adjective can also combine with accusatives that cannot stand alone in a temporal (temperospatial?) function, e.g. *Einen Kilometer später kam schon die nächste Baustelle*.

Comment: @mach I have updated the answer. I do not see this accusative as adverbial, but as governed by the adjective. (I see no point in viewing *einen Tag später* as an example where an adverbial accusative modifies an adjective and *einen Kilometer später* or *den Ärger gewohnt* as examples where an adjective governs the accusative.)

Comment: @DavidVogt: The difference becomes evident by the substitution test: adverbial accusatives can be replaced by adverbs, accusative objects by pronouns: In cases like *einen Tag später* or *ich warte einen Tag,* you can substitute *einen Tag* by the adverb *lange,* but in cases like *ich bin den Ärger gewohnt* or *ich erwarte den Ärger,* you can subsitute *den Ärger* by the pronoun *ihn.*

Comment: @mach I have reworded the answer so as to be agnostic to the status of these accusatives as complements or adjuncts.

Answer (score 7):

In a German sentence, basically any part that isn't subject, object or predicative can be seen as a so called [Adverbial](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbiale_Bestimmung). An Adverbial modifies the sentence by adding additional information, similar to how an adverb or adverbial clause in English can.

If you use a noun or a noun phrase as an Adverbial, you can express the way of the modification by the case. For example, an *Adverbial des Zeitpunktes* (adverbial of point of time) uses the genetive

> Das wird euch *eines Tages* noch leid tun!

The accusative is used, among other uses, for periods of time

> Ich habe *den ganzen Nachmittag* geschlafen.

or, as in your example sentence, the dimension

> Es ist *nur einen Zentimeter* groß.

There are also terms like "adverbialer Genetiv" or "adverbialer Akkusativ".

Comment: I think *nur einen Zentimeter* modifies *groß* rather than the sentence, but I take your meaning that when a noun phrase is used as a modifier then it takes the accusative case. To me, *eines Tages* and related expressions are figures of speech which don't need a grammatical explanation. The British have a similar expression but with a different meaning, for example "It's normally just a fry-up for me of an evening, ..." from "Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban". I'm not sure if I can translate that to American, much less German.